# Is this closed form expression of $\zeta(3)$ correct?

Tags: riemann-zeta

In this [paper](http://hp.hisashikobayashi.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Hozumi_paper_L-function-odd-3.pdf) on pages 6 & 7. Page 6 lists the variables used in the equation on page 7.

The author claims a closed form expression of $\zeta(3)$ (he also goes on to claim a closed form expression of $\zeta(2n+1)$ ). I tried calculating it in my calculator and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288/3%29%282/3%2api%5E3%29%5Bsin%284pi/5%29%289/250%29%2bsin%282pi/5%29%286/125%29%2bsin%282pi/5%29%2821/500%29%2bsin%284pi/5%29%283/125%29%5D-%2816/3%29%282/3%2api%5E3%29%5Bsin%282pi/5%29%286/125%29%2bsin%284pi/5%29%283/125%29%5D%2b%282/3%29%282/3%2api%5E3%29%5B-sin%284pi/5%29%286/125%29%2bsin%282pi/5%29%283/125%29%5D) as well, but get an answer of $0$ both times.

I am new to reading math papers, but I believe I interpreted the equation of $\zeta(3)$ correctly. Please let me know where I went wrong.

Comment: Waiting for an expert!

Comment: Related: [Apéry's constant (ζ(3)) value](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382620/aperys-constant-zeta3-value).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To save all of us the trouble, I evaluated the formula in the paper and it is ***incorrect*** (perhaps not a surprise). In page 7, the author gives it as,

$$\zeta(3)= \frac{8}{3}u\,\big(\beta\,B(\tfrac{1}{10}) + \alpha\,B(\tfrac{2}{10}) + \alpha\,B(\tfrac{3}{10}) + \beta\,B(\tfrac{4}{10})\big) - \frac{16}{3}u\big(\alpha\,B(\tfrac{1}{5}) +\beta\,B(\tfrac{2}{5})\big) + \frac{2}{3}u\big(-\beta\,B(\tfrac{1}{5}) + \alpha\,B(\tfrac{2}{5})\big)\tag{1}$$

where,

$$u = \frac{2\pi^3}{3},\;\;\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{8}},\;\;\beta = \sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{8}},\;\;B(x) = x(x-\tfrac{1}{2})(x-1)$$

As the OP also noticed, the expression (1) in fact, ***is equal to zero***. (Among other things, the $\sqrt{5}$ was already a bad sign.)

Comment: @Mike: $3$ is not in the critical strip...